# Understanding this behavior of multiprocessing, involving shared_memory, Process and Lock

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, locking, shared-memory

I'm currently starting to learn about the `multiprocessing` library in python. Concretely, how to share memory (a numpy array) between the main process and a child process using the [`shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) module.

For that, I am using a toy script from which I am getting a result that I don't understand. I'm defining a class which stores as attributes the memory that is going to be shared (`shm`), as well as a `lock`.

Given this, after instanciating the class, I start a `process` using the instance as argument to it, so that `shm` and `lock` are also shared. After doing so, and using `lock`, I modify and print the value contained in `shm`.

After this, and also using `lock`, I print `shm` value using a method from the class.

This is the code I'm using:

```py
from multiprocessing import shared_memory, Process, Lock
import numpy as np
import time


def work(foo):
    existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=foo.shm.name)

    a = np.ndarray(
        foo.shared_array.shape,
        dtype=foo.shared_array.dtype,
        buffer=existing_shm.buf
        )

    with foo.lock:
        print(a)
        a[0] = 1.0
        print(a)


class Foo:

    def __init__(self):

        a = np.zeros(10,)
        self.shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=a.nbytes)
        self.shared_array = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=np.int64, buffer=self.shm.buf)
        self.shared_array[:] = a[:]

        self.lock = Lock()

    def start_process(self):
        self.process = Process(target=work, args=(self,))
        self.process.start()

    def show(self):
        with self.lock:
            print(self.shared_array)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
    foo.start_process()
    # time.sleep(2)
    foo.show()
```

And the result is:

```bash
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

However, I would expect the following output:

```bash
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Curiously, after uncommenting `time.sleep(2)`, I get the above expected output. Since `lock` is being used and (I think) this makes `foo.show()` to be stopped until the `lock` from `work` is realeased, I don't get why this happens.

Any help is highly appreciated.

PD: As a sidenote, is this bad practice? since sending the whole instance as argument to a process may result in pickling it, thus misusing `shm`?

PD2: I'm using Windows OS and python 3.9.

Comment: your main process is ending before the child process has time to startup, so `foo.show` is called before the array is modified by the child process. this is a race condition (which operation happens first) which is why adding a delay makes it more likely that the child will have modified the array first. A better solution is to use `Process.join()` to explicitly wait for the child process to complete before moving on.

Comment: @Aaron thanks, that makes total sense. Calling `Process.join()` as a first step in `show` method would definitely solve this problem. If I may ask, if the process is intended to be called once to be running a signficant time, is it considered bad practice to send the whole instance to the process (considering that I will be needing all its atributes?

Comment: Because `self` is not shared, rather copied when you call `Process(target=work, args=(self,))`, I tend to try to create my class instances inside `target` to avoid the overhead of sending it to the new process. (you can't get away from paying to create the instance at least once, but you can avoid paying to copy and re-create it). This means generally the only useful `args` for the new process are generally constants, and \[collections of\] actually shared objects / mutexes.

Comment: @Aaron I see your point, thanks again. I may stick with the previous approach (sharing `self`) since in my problem all the attributes of the class will be used in the launched process. Thus, I believe the effect of copying/ creating a new object would be the same. However I agree with you that if that is not the case, then a better and cleaner approach would be the one you commented.